# Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 24 (Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime )

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpCustomers(
[CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomerCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CustomerName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[LeftCount] [int] NULL,
[RightCount] [int] NULL,
[CreationDate][datetime]null,
)

DECLARE Customer_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT customerid
FROM Customers
OPEN Customer_Cursor;

declare @left  int
declare @right int
declare @customerid int

FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor into @customerid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  EXEC dbo.CountChildren @customerId,@left out,@right out

    insert into #tmpCustomers 
    select customerId,[CustomerCode],[CustomerName],(CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,2), Creationdate)),@left,@right from Customers where CustomerID=@customerid
   FETCH NEXT FROM Customer_Cursor into @customerid;
END;

select *, case when  leftcount>RightCount then RightCount else LeftCount end as Pairs from #tmpCustomers a
drop table #tmpCustomers
CLOSE Customer_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Customer_Cursor;
```

Here is code , this code is giving following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 24
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Please guide me how to set it.

Comment: What is the data type of `CreationDate` and why are you converting it to `NUMERIC`. The problem could simply be that you are not specifying the columns when inserting into `#tmpCustomers`.

Comment: i want creatiodate in output , code was giving correct output before adding creationdate ... so problem is in creationdate...

Comment: creatiodate data type is datetime()

Comment: the output of creationdate column i get from above code :

Comment: CreationDate
1902-02-15 00:00:00.000  ...... year value is not correct in output

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to stick a largeish `INT` into a `DATETIME` column, the conversion to `NUMERIC` seems unesseccary but do try specifing the columns in the insert statement i.e `INSERT INTO #tmp (col1, col2 ...) SELECT col1, col2 ... FROM tbl`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that look wrong:

1. You are converting a datetime to a numeric value, which gives you the number of days (and fractional days) since 1900-01-01.  I don't see why that's necessary in your code.
2. The columns don't line up properly in your INSERT statement.  You are inserting a  `NUMERIC(18,2)` value (due to the `CONVERT`) into an integer field and an `int` value into a `DATETIME` field.  That's probably why you're seeing the wrong values for `CreationDate` in your results.

I suspect you want something like:

```
INSERT INTO #tmpCustomers 
SELECT 
    customerId,
    [CustomerCode],
    [CustomerName],
    @left,
    @right, 
    Creationdate
FROM Customers 
WHERE CustomerID=@customerid
```

Comment: yes , and in output there should be correct value of Creationdate....(2013-08-21 h:m:s:mm)

Comment: In your current query you're inserting the value of `@right` into `CreationDate` since it's the last column in the temp table and your `SELECT`, so that's probably why you're seeing the wrong values.

Comment: sir actually i want creationdate in output , so please what should b in code to get creationdate in output.

Comment: yes i corrected it as u said and run the query , will update when it finishd.

Comment: It will still be in your output - you just need to correct the order of your column in your INSERT statement.

Comment: sir i got the correct result .. :)  one more thing i want in output if u help me....?

Comment: CustomerName='GL 56460'

Comment: some customers have CustomerName = 'GL 56460' i want a seprate column in which there should b 'GoldenLine' agains each row of that customer who have customername ='GL someid '...

Comment: `CASE WHEN customername LIKE 'GL %' THEN 'GoldenLine' ELSE NULL END`